# C++ Inherited Constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am currently developing a c++ program with the main purpose being you have two different objects which float around the screen, crash into each other, etc. 
Anyway the problem that I am having is that I need to derive two classes from my base class. However in the definition and declaration of my derived class I am getting an error and cant work it out. I have searched the net and sought advice from my colleagues however am unable to find the source of the problem. the code is

```
Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console);
```

(For the header file)

and

```
Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console): Element(rnd, console){};
```

(For the cpp file)

The error I am getting is IntelliSense:

> Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console)" provides no initializer for:  e:\c++\my game\my game\jetsam.cpp.

Does anyone have any idea of what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Cheers guys, Alyn.

As requested:

### JETSAM

```
#pragma once
#include "RandomNumber.h"
#include "Console.h"
#include "element.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Jetsam : public Element
{
public:
    Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console);
    ~Jetsam();
    void printAt(void);

protected:
    RandomNumber &rnd;
    Console &console;
};
```

### Element

```
#pragma once
#include "RandomNumber.h"
#include "Console.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// code shell, amend as appropriate

class Element
{
protected:
    RandomNumber &rnd;
    Console &console;
    int x;
    int y;
    int energy;
    int direction;
    int speed;
    char identifier;
    static char nextIdentifier;

public:

    Element();
    Element(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console);
    // precondition: references to RandomNumber and Console objects are provided, along with any other desired parameters
    // postcondition: Element object created and private members initialised
    // example of use: Element element(rnd, console);


    virtual void print(void);
    // precondition: none
    // postcondition: identifier, x and y are sent to the standard output
    // example of use: element.print();

    virtual void printAt(void)=0;
    // precondition: none
    // postcondition: text background is changed proportionate to its energy in the following order
    //                BLUE, GREEN, AQUA, YELLOW, RED, PURPLE, e.g. an object with 23 energy would have an AQUA background
    //                object's identifier is sent to the standard output at its x, y coordinates
    // example of use: element.printAt();

    int getX(void);
    int getY(void);
    int getEnergy(void);
    int getDirection(void);
    int getSpeed(void);
    //getters for the base class
    void setX(int);
    void sety(int);
    void setEnergy(int);
    void setDirection(int);
    void setSpeed(int);
    //setters for the base class
};
```

Comment: Suspect you want `Element(rnd, console)`, unless `Element` takes pointer types as arguments.

Comment: Please post the definition of classes `Element` and `Jetsam`; I suspect there's a member in `Jetsam` which needs explicit initialisation, such as a `const` member or a reference.

Comment: I meant the definitions of the classes, not of their member functions. That is, show what's in the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both the classes `Element` and `Jetsam` define these members:

```
RandomNumber &rnd;
Console &console;
```

This means each instance of `Jetsam` actually has two of these: `Element::rnd` and `Jetsam::rnd`. As they're references, they have to be initialised in the mem-initialiser list of the constructor; there's no other way to initialise them.

To simply fix the error, you'd have to do this:

```
Jetsam::Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console) :
  Element(rnd, console)
  , rnd(rnd)
  , console(console)
{}
```

However, I suspect you don't really want them duplicated (especially since they're `protected` inside `Element`). So the correct solution would be to simply remove their declarations from `Jetsam`. After that, `Jetsam` would look like this:

```
class Jetsam : public Element
{
public:
    Jetsam(RandomNumber &rnd, Console &console);
    ~Jetsam();
    virtual void printAt(void);
};
```

Note that it's generally a good idea to repeat the `virtual` keyword when overriding virtual functions in derived classes (it helps readability), even though it's not required by the standard. Of course, with C++11 compilers which support it, `override` is even more preferable.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your time and answer. I totally understand now and can see exactly where I have gone wrong :). Thank you very much.